# Does the "alternating" harmonic series where only prime terms are negative converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

We know that the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, yet the alternating harmonic series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges.

Euler famously gave a proof of the infinitude (and of the "density") of primes by showing that the series $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ diverges; this reasoning can be applied more generally to show Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

Can this reasoning lead to the stronger statement that $\sum \frac{\epsilon(n)}{n}$ converges, where $\epsilon(n)$ is $1$ if $n$ is prime and $-1$ otherwise? If this isn't true (which I suspect but can't easily prove), is there any relationship between whether an "alternating" harmonic series like this, where we give a $+$ sign to numbers in some set $S$ and a $-$ to others, converged and whether the sum of the harmonic series restricted to $S$ converges? Perhaps the case where $S$ is an arithmetic progression is easy?

What if we generalize further to partitions of the positive integers into $n$ parts and consider the harmonic sum where there's a different $n^{th}$ root of unity for each part? This feels like something related to Dirichlet zeta functions and characters of finite groups, but I don't know how to make this precise.

Comment: If you had $\epsilon(n) = +1$ when $n$ is a multiple of three and $-1$ otherwise, this would diverge because the negative terms outgrow the positive ones.  The same thing is true for your question, only the primes are so rare that not even 0.0001% of all terms will be positive (in the long run).  This is kind of like hoping $\lim_{x\to\infty} x - e^x$ will exist just because $x$ and $e^x$ both diverge to infinity.

Comment: Thanks! I must have gotten carried away...

Comment: For a similar problem that actually has somewhat balanced behavior, try Liouville's function $-1$ to the power of the number of prime factors of $n$.  [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.1029v1.pdf) also discusses a root-of-unity analogue which you speculate near the end of your question.

Comment: If you want to quantify exactly how far away you got carried, you could read up on [Mertens' second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)...

Comment: Wow, so I guess you could say the asymptotic behavior of $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ is as different from that of $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ as $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is to $\sum 1$! (since the former is between $\log \log n$ and $\log n$ and the latter between $\log n$ and $n$)

Comment: @Dorebell In fact it is sometimes said that $\sum 1/p$ diverges so slowly that $\sum 1/p$ over all known primes is less than $4$.  There was a question on MSE that discussed the validity of this claim, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: @Dorebell Here's the question I was looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831829/sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-for-known-primes.  Thanks to the anonymous upvoter who brought it to my attention!

Answer (score 3):

We have two well-known asymptotics,

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{n \leq N} \frac{1}{n} &\sim \log N \\
\sum_{p \leq N} \frac{1}{p} &\sim \log \log N.
\end{align}$$

The difference in magnitude between these is so large that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \frac{\epsilon(n)}{n} \gg \log N$$
still, and so your sum still diverges.

More generally, you can hope for convergence if you choose $\epsilon(n)$ in such a way that the partial sums
$$ \sum_{n \leq N} \epsilon(n)$$
are uniformly bounded by some number $M$. This is the case in the regular harmonic series, as the partial sums are bounded by $1$. In the case of primes, the resulting partial sums diverge to infinity as "most" integers are not prime.

However, if the partial sums are uniformly bounded, then one can use [Dirichlet's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) to show that the resulting pseudo-alternating harmonic series converges. This applies even if one chooses the weights to be roots of unity instead of $\pm 1$.